# Partitioning sets such that the sum of 2 elements is Prime

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, prime-numbers

Given an $n >0$ is it possible to partition the set $\mathcal{P} = \{1,2, \cdots, 2n\}$ into $n$ pairs $(a_{i},b_{i})$ such that $a_{i} + b_{i}$ is a prime?

Comment: @Nuno: I have removed the set theory related tag altogether.

Comment: @Moron: I agree. I thought of removing the tag set-theory, but let it go. Thanks for the change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  The proof is by strong induction.  The base case is obvious.  By [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrands_postulate) there exists a prime $p$ between $2n+1$ and $4n$, so pick the pairs $\{ p-2n, 2n \}, \{ p-2n+1, 2n-1 \}, ...$ and so forth.  Now it remains to pair up the numbers $\{ 1, 2, ... p-2n-1 \}$, which is possible by the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I think the way you partitioned the set is a bit wrong. You can create the pairs ranging from $<p-2n,2n>...<p-n,n>$. The remaining subset yet to be partitioned is $\{p-(n-1),..,1\}$ which by induction you have the necessary partition.